# Error rebaseing/updating a git-svn repository

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

Hoping this is not a dup, I didn't find any concise information on how to update a git-svn repo. I used git svn clone to import an SVN repo into git. Then, after doing some commits, I wanted to rebase with regards to the original SVN repo.

```
C:\Work\osqa>git svn rebase
Migrating from a git-svn v1 layout...
Data from a previous version of git-svn exists, but
        .git/svn
        (required for this version (1.7.3.1.msysgit.0) of git-svn) does not exis
t.
Done migrating from a git-svn v1 layout
forum/views/readers.py: needs update
update-index --refresh: command returned error: 1
```

When I repeated the git svn rebase command a second time, I got just the tail of the last message:

```
C:\Work\osqa>git svn rebase
forum/views/readers.py: needs update
update-index --refresh: command returned error: 1
```

I'm not sure what the error message means. Can you help resolve it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I recall correctly, that means that there are uncommitted changes to that file. What's the output of `git status`?

Comment: Yes, but you've got uncommitted changes to the file it complains about. Either commit or stash them and try again.

Comment: That was (part of) the problem indeed. I just realized that git-svn does not persist its metadata. I think I have been working on a fresh copy that didn't have the SVN metadata at all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368819/is-there-a-way-to-persistently-synchronize-a-git-repository-with-svn

Comment: You can push commits in git without doing git stash every time. Since it seems to me that `git svn dcommit` is essentially `git push` it seems to me that `git stash` ought not be necessary..

Answer (score 5):

If you are working on a Windows system and the output of `git status` returns "no changes added to commit", it may be a problem with the file attributes on FAT file system. Try executing `git config core.fileMode false`

Also the `autocrlf` setting could cause this.

Comment: Happened to me on a machine with dual boot, Fedora + Windows, and a partition that I created as NTFS so that I can share it between the two operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have uncommitted file changes.

```
git status
# if you see pending changes, you can do multiple things
```

1. Stash them and pull latest and revisit them.

   `git stash`
   `git svn rebase`
   `git stash pop`
2. If changes are intended and u like to commit it.

   `git add <file>`
   `git commit -m '<commit message>'`
   `git svn rebase`