# Is there a way to "persistently" synchronize a git repository with SVN?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

From what I could find around the web, it seems that using `git svn` is not "persisted".

Meaning, if I `git svn clone` a repository, then push to master and repull a fresh copy in a separate folder, the fresh copy is not aware of svn at all, and cannot be used to synchronize with SVN without reapplication of `svn clone`.

Is there a way around this issue?

Comment: Thomas Ferris Nicolaisen wrote an article series about your environment. http://www.tfnico.com/presentations/git-and-subversion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A clone essentially just initializes a new git repository, sets up the `origin` remote, runs `git fetch`, and creates a branch based on the remote repository's `HEAD`.  None of these operations look at the `.git/svn` information in the remote repository - I think that everything apart from `refs`, `objects` and `HEAD` in a remote repository's git directory is regarded as private.

As for a way around that, you could always `rsync -a` or `scp -r` the remote repository instead of cloning it, which should work - all the Subversion metadata should be copied.

However, personally I've always found it less confusing to just have one `git svn` cloned repository that I do `git svn dcommit` from, and push back to that repository whenever I want to commit anything to Subversion.  Then those other repositories are just normal git repositories and you don't need to worry about any of the restrictions of `git svn` until you push back to the `git svn` clone, at which point you normally need to do some rebasing...

Answer (score 1):

I find the easiest way is to `git svn init` the clone with the same parameters you used for creating the first git-svn clone, followed by an update-ref and a dcommit.

Say you did:

> git svn clone -s svn://server/website

.. to create the first repo. Then you would clone it:

```
git clone website website2
cd website2
```

Initialize git-svn:

```
git svn init -s svn://server/website
```

Now you've got to update the git-svn remote reference to point at the last commit, for example:

> git update-ref refs/remotes/trunk refs/remotes/origin/HEAD

And then just do an git svn dcommit to rebuild the git-svn revmap.

> git svn dcommit

You should see some output like this:

```
git svn dcommit
Rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/trunk/.rev_map.dbae88...
r1 = a9cf429caa11ba5433a6526c2d327de6db2605d1
r2 = 2811ffb78c0a9e0a74208758367044710c1c0159
r4 = 1b787f296aeb98806875ca4f2bde67131720cd57
r9 = 991400ef398fad17ca14253467997d4764561cff
r11 = c5984281dd185d3dbb3bf3fa26f168f34d4e4b53
r13 = aa7678d2f9b5f87152ab09a59ea11a4643e84b6c
r14 = 1c91c959e3bbd2d41dd001a670d01abef29ae1ad
Done rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/trunk/.rev_map.dbae88...
Committing to svn://server/website/trunk ...
```

For more background, have a look at [this post](http://blog.tfnico.com/2010/11/git-svn-mirror-for-multiple-branches.html), especially point 5.

Answer (score 0):

GIT-SVN SNIPPETS: http://marcocattai.posterous.com/git-svn-snippets

I hope they're useful.