# Why am I getting this error trying to use git with svn

Tags: git, git-svn

Why am I getting this error trying to use git with svn. I am doing the following steps and getting some crazy errors.

```
git svn clone -s http://svn/java/project project
cd project
git svn show-ignore > .gitignore
git checkout -b dev
```

I get the following outpput

```
M   src/main/java/app.properties
M   src/main/java/messages.properties
M   src/main/java/org/xxxxx/enrollment/dao/projectDao.java
M   src/main/resources/app.properties
M   src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flows/start/footer.jsp
M   src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flows/start/header_edit.jsp
M   src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flows/start/tobe.jsp
M   src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/mvc.xml
M   src/main/webapp/index.jsp
M   src/test/resources/app.properties
M   src/test/resources/messages.properties
M   src/test/resources/mvc.xml
Switched to a new branch 'dev
```

'

```
git svn rebase
```

I get this output

```
src/main/java/app.properties: needs update
src/main/java/messages.properties: needs update
src/main/java/org/xxxx/enrollment/dao/projectDao.java: needs update
src/main/resources/app.properties: needs update
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flows/start/footer.jsp: needs update
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flows/start/header_edit.jsp: needs update
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flows/start/tobe.jsp: needs update
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/mvc.xml: needs update
src/main/webapp/index.jsp: needs update
src/test/resources/app.properties: needs update
src/test/resources/messages.properties: needs update
src/test/resources/mvc.xml: needs update
update-index --refresh: command returned error: 1
```

please help me

Comment: What does `git status` say in "master" before you try to create the new branch?

Comment: Are you in a mixed OS development environment where different users might be on systems with different line-ending conventions (Windows vs Linux vs MacOS)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820178/why-am-i-getting-this-error-trying-to-use-git-with-svn#comment20764483_14820178) by [twalberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253222/twalberg), and illustrated in [issue 103](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=103), make sure that you type, *before* cloning and rebasing:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

You don't want git changing anything automatically (as in "[Error rebaseing/updating a `git-svn` repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7090618/6309)").

Comment: @techsjs2013 commit? It adds an entry in your global gitconfig (~/.gitconfig), in order to make sure it doesn't change the end of line (I mistakenly mentioned only `fileMode`: I replaced it by `autocrlf`)

Comment: @techsjs2013 a bit like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13888206/6309. For `autocrlf`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlf-true-in-git and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333424/distributing-git-configuration-with-the-code/2354278#2354278