# When git svn dcommit can be used?

Tags: git, svn, staging, dcommit

I want to learn how to use git with svn repository.

I follow this manual: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion

I make some changes in my file. Some of them staged, some of them not:

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   CHANGES.txt
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   CHANGES.txt
#
```

According to the manual I first commit staged changes into my local repository:

```
$ git commit -m "new"
[master 21bf2bd] new
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

now I have only unstages changes, which I want to live like it is for the future commits:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   CHANGES.txt
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

And I want to push local commits upstream to svn:

```
$ git svn dcommit         
CHANGES.txt: needs update
update-index --refresh: command returned error: 1
```

Why can't I do it?

**When can I use "dcommit" and when I can't?** I clearly lack this information, and I wasn't able to find more description in google or [man pages](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html).

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367734/error-rebaseing-updating-a-git-svn-repository

Answer (score 2):

You can't have any non-commited changes when you do dcommit.

To temporarily hide your modifications, use `git stash`. Then commit with `git svn dcommit`, and finally pop the stash with `git stash pop` to enable your modifications once again.